# Excel Automation: Open existing Excel file as "new"

Tags: c#, excel, automation, export-to-excel

I want to have a "one-click" excel export feature for my application. I therefore need to create an excel file in a temporary location, because I need to use a third-party component to do so.

I want Excel to then open up the file. I can get to that point; however Excel always remembers the location it loaded the file from. I'd like the loaded file to appear as a "new" file which is not saved to a specific location, so when the user wants to hit "save" (not save as) or close Excel it reminds them of unsaved changes.

I'm using Excel Automation from C# on .net 3.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify any existing Excel workbook as the template. Then you use the [Workbooks.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.add(office.11).aspx) method to open a new workbook, with the Template parameter pointing to the temporary template.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... try creating and excel template instead and then open the template instead?